# Importing a class in vanilla JavaScript isn't working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I was making a cool graphic for my website when I got this weird bug. I import a class called 'Particle' from particle.js and I also give it HTML5 Canvas' 2dRenderingContextAPI too. Please take a look at my code and tell where I went wrong. I expect a black rectangle to be drawn on Canvas.

```js
//This is the file attached to the document


//Imports
import Particle from "./particle.js";

//Global Variables
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const particle = new Particle(ctx);

//Animation Loop
function animate() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 139, 0.2)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    particle.draw();

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#canvas1 {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bouncing particles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>

    <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my particle.js file:

```js
//This is particle.js

export default class Particle {
    constructor(ctx) {
        this.height = 100;
        this.width = 100;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
    draw() {
        this.ctx.fillRect(50, 50, this.height, this.width);
    }
}
```

Comment: "isn't working" is not a useful problem statement ... what debugging have you done? are their errors in the browser console perhaps?

Comment: If there is CORS errors then you need to run your html file on local server

Comment: though, since your fillStyle is `'rgba(0, 0, 139, 0.2)'` for the whole canvas AND the particle ... how could you tell it's not drawn?

Comment: Nope.. There aren't any errors in the console...

Comment: so, I ask again ... with one fill color, how can you tell the particle isn't drawn

Comment: It worked! I saw that the problem was that I was constantly drawing a black rect on the canvas. Such a foolish mistake! Thank you Bravo!

Comment: what worked? changing the colour of the "particle"?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was drawing that transparent rect for getting a black trail...

Comment: No.. I stopped drawing that transparent rectangle over canvas, It was blocking me from seeing the rect